How to programatically open <select> list on Mac
In the Chrome browser on Windows, when a <select> element receives focus, pressing the ENTER key will reveal the list of options. However, this is not the case on Mac. So far I have not found a way to do this programmatically, short of building a custom solution.
Below are the different approaches I have tried:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Approach 1: Native Focus + Click
  const select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
  select1.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('Approach 1: Native Focus + Click');
      select1.focus();
      select1.click();
    }
  });

  // Approach 2: Native Focus + Mousedown
  const select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
  select2.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('Approach 2: Native Focus + Mousedown');
      select2.focus();
      const mousedownEvent = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window,
      });
      select2.dispatchEvent(mousedownEvent);
    }
  });

  // Approach 3: Native Focus + Simulate ArrowDown
  const select3 = document.getElementById('select3');
  select3.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('Approach 3: Native Focus + Simulate ArrowDown');
      select3.focus();
      const arrowDownEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        key: 'ArrowDown',
        code: 'ArrowDown',
        keyCode: 40,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      });
      select3.dispatchEvent(arrowDownEvent)
    }
  });

  // Approach 4: Custom Dropdown
  const customDropdown = document.getElementById('custom-dropdown');
  const customOptions = document.getElementById('custom-options');
  const customSelected = document.getElementById('custom-selected');

  customDropdown.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('Approach 4: Custom Dropdown (Simulated)');
      const isExpanded = customDropdown.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';
      customDropdown.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !isExpanded);
      customOptions.hidden = isExpanded;
    }
  });

  customOptions.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    customSelected.textContent = event.target.textContent;
    customDropdown.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    customOptions.hidden = true;
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Experiment with Dropdown Approaches</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Select Dropdown Approaches</h1>
  <p>Focus on each dropdown and press <strong>Enter</strong>. Check the console to see logs and experiment with different approaches.</p>

  <div>
    <h2>Approach 1: Native Focus + Click</h2>
    <label for="select1">Dropdown:</label>
    <select id="select1">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Approach 2: Native Focus + Mousedown</h2>
    <label for="select2">Dropdown:</label>
    <select id="select2">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Approach 3: Native Focus + Simulate ArrowDown</h2>
    <label for="select3">Dropdown:</label>
    <select id="select3">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Approach 4: Custom Dropdown (Simulated)</h2>
    <div id="custom-dropdown" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false">
      <div id="custom-selected">Select an option</div>
      <ul id="custom-options" role="listbox" hidden>
        <li role="option">Option 1</li>
        <li role="option">Option 2</li>
        <li role="option">Option 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




In mac you have to use the arrow keys after focus. this might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

On Windows, when a <select> element receives focus, pressing the ENTER key will reveal the list of options - except, it doesn't behave that way in Firefox - so, it's not an operating system behaviour, it's a browser specific (Chrome) behaviour

[Alt] + [down arrow] will open your select and reveal the list of options -> Firefox Linux. There is always a keyboard combination to open a select on any browser.
